# the non-zero integer roots of an inequality

Tags: number-theory

Let $a,b,c,d$ be real numbers, and $ad-bc \ne 0$, given
$$|(ax+by)(cx+dy)|\le \frac{1}{2}|ad-bc|.$$

does there exist non-zero integers $x,y$ which satisfy the above inequality ?

Comment: Do you mean to say that there exist integers $x, y$ which satisfy the above inequality ?

Comment: @Debashish Yes,that's what I mean

Comment: Couldn't you just make $x$ and $y$ really small, without actually making them $0$. That way you could get the LHS smaller than any positive number you want.

Comment: @Bolt64         friend。。。I want x,y to be integers.

Comment: @user92646 Sorry, my bad. :P

Comment: Try with picking smallest positive x such that $c/d < y/x < a/b $ (inequality signs switched around if necessary). The inequality looks lopsided to me through, as it is not really homogenous.

Comment: @CalvinLin    bro,can you tell me the detail?

Comment: Do you allow one of $x, y$ to be zero?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti       Yes, one of them can be zero